# Embed office (Word Excel) into WinForms or WPF control

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-office

Is it possible to embed Office application in WinForms control (having office installed on computer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add these using statements:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then you can add `ExcelObj` and add a `Workbork` and a `Worksheet` to that. Its all pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can create excel objecst like that but is it possible to view them in my winforms or WPF application ?

Comment: For example just view excel workbook or word document witch reduced (if not only view) functionality. And then for example add two buttons to move from age to next or previous (in word case)

Comment: Just found a link which uses thia method, and allows you to integrate the interfaces themselves: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Embedding_Excel.aspx

Comment: It doesnt work, It opens workbook in other windows as other application

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Excel is available as a control and you can use it. Look for licensing issues if any.

Comment: Could You please give me a link to information about that controll? I cant find it

Comment: There is a similar query on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757023/embed-excel-sheet-in-c-user-control

Comment: It doesnt work, It opens workbook in other windows as other application