# How to switch applications when it is opened in the taskbar of desktop with WinApp driver

Tags: c#, appium, desktop, winappdriver

I am working with Winapp driver, appium and c# where i am automating a desktop application.
My scerios is: I have aplication where i click on the button which opens excel sheet which is now shows in Taskbar of the desktop. Now i want to switch to the excel sheet from my desktop application.

I am not able to find a single solution for the same. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907032/11362349)  it may help

Answer (score 0):

1.) Try getting WindowHandles() by :

```
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

If this set has 2 values, then you can easily switch between both the apps via :

```
driver.switchTo.window(windowHandleOfExcel);
```

2.) If the set contains only one handle, then you need to create a new Desktop session for you excel , you can do the same by :

```
//get a root driver 
//all the opened application will be children of this root driver
//get the expected child driver

 DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("app", "Root");
        WindowsDriver rootDriver = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), cap);


 WebElement ele = d.findElementByName("Book - Excel"); //Pass the header or title of the excel opened
        String toplevel = ele.getAttribute("NativeWindowHandle");
        int x  = (Integer.parseInt(toplevel));
        toplevel = Integer.toHexString(x);


DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("appTopLevelWindow", toplevel);
        WindowsDriver childdriver = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), cap);
```

childDriver is the driver that is pointing for the Excel app.

Hope this helps.