# Embedding OneNote in an application

Tags: c#, c++, onenote

I want to embed(make OneNote a control) in my application. I know Excel is possible using a control in .Net but I don't know how to make OneNote embedded. The languages I can use are C++ or C#.

Answer (score 3):

OneNote does not provide a control that can be used to embed it into another application. The only API set available allows reading and writing OneNote data. Therefore what you are looking for is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comprehensive summary of OneNote programmability options, with code samples, for various Office versions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796230.aspx).

Briefly, there is a COM API for versions >= 2003 SP1, and for 2007 or 2010, an Object Model you can use for richer interaction.

Comment: +1 for the nice link, but I don't think that answers the original question. He wants to embed a OneNote control in his application.

Comment: @Nemanja - how would accessing One Note data (using ONOM) be different from the Excel example here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757023/embed-excel-sheet-in-c-user-control

Comment: Embedding is not the same thing as programatically reading data. You can embed Excel worksheets in your Win32 apps like this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/vcgeneral/thread/6B7A8D36-95E3-45E8-AA7F-99775BE830C9

Comment: @Nemanja - does the info here -http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/508465/interop-type-onenote-application-cannot-be-embedded - help?  Seems like that is the correct scenario. There is a project config tweak to allow OneNote embedding via the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application` PIA.